# Style is not loading in local html using WKWebView when css file is in parent folder

Tags: css, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

My Xamarin Forms application downloads several HTML files (stored in .../Application/{AppId}/Documents/) that use the same CSS file . The problem is that when I link the CSS sheet to an HTML file that is at a lower level, the CSS can't load.

Ex :

```
[Documents]
    style.css
    [folder]
        index.html
```

Example of the **index.html**

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            Some content
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*You can see here that I'm using the `../` to get to the previous level.*

According to the tests I've done, this only happened in the iOS on a real device. The simulator's working fine.

I opened Safari with the html inspector and indeed HTML cannot access the CSS file.

It also works well if the CSS file is below/equal to the HTML file.

On the other hand, it is present when I run `File.Exist({CssPathFile})`.

I also tried to add the reference to the css file in JS with the HTML Inspector and I got : 
`Failed to load resource: ... (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 1.)`

Comment: Hi , *It also works well if the CSS file is below/equal to the HTML file.* I think below/equal is the suggest ways , not above the level .

Comment: I do understand. But for technical reasons it need to be at the above level :/. Is that the *suggest ways* or a limitation? Thank you!

Comment: Not sure a limitation . It happens on a physical ios device , now only can using this way as a workaround . You ara right , maybe call it as a suggest ways is not correct , because a normal web application has the structure of above level .

Comment: Yes I do agree. And I can confirm that it is working on iOS simulator... I don't know if it is a security "feature" of iOS ‍♂️

Comment: You can update this ( *below/equal to the level* ) as an workaround in answer . Later if other people occur the same phenomenon will discuss here whether this is a strange "feature" in iOS physical device ...